# let arr = [10, 20, 30, 10, 5, 7, 7]; написать функцию чтоб узнать какой элемент сколько раз повторяется

Tags: javascript

```
let arr = [10, 20, 30, 10, 5, 7, 7]
```

Comment: Ну а в чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: не знаю как написать

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [10, 20, 30, 10, 5, 7, 7];
let obj = {};
arr.forEach((el,index,array)=>{
     obj[el] = array.filter(item => item==el).length
})
console.log(obj);
```